# Select datas From Nested Array

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem, i've datas like this

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ticket");
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$data_workgroup=$r['workgroup'];
$explode= explode(",",$data_workgroup);
print_r($explode);
```

and I get this

```
Array ( [0] => Technical Support)
Array ( [0] => Marketing [1] => Network Engineer )
Array ( [0] => Technical Support )
Array ( [0] => Technical Support [1] => Network Engineer )
```

i need to get value from that array, so i can show data just for Workgroup Value

```
SELECT * FROM ticket where workgroup = ValueOFArray[Network Engineer/Technical Support]
```

Hope you can help Me. Sorry I Can't post Images. thanks :)

Comment: sorry like this `Select * FROM ticket, Division where Division.name_division = valueOFARRAY`

Answer (score 0):

$explode is just a multidimensional array , so :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ticket where workgroup = '".explode[0][0]."';";
```

And you will execute a query like :

```
SELECT * FROM ticket where workgroup = 'Technical Support';
```

More here: 
http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

Comment: sorry i've fault from my first post `Select * FROM ticket, Division where Division.name_division = valueOFARRAY`
I want to get value from array.